# send parameter from routes to htmlfile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

i have an application in nodejs. now i am sending a parameter along with the url which i want to use in the script part of html. below is my code present in route :

```
app.use('/overview',function(req, res) {
module.exports.dbname = req.query.dbname; 
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/html', 'overview.html'));
});
```

Below is the code present in my overview.html file:

```
<script>
  function cb(start, end) {
   $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
   filter = {
       "start" : start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
       "end" : end.format('YYYY-MM-DD '),
       "gender" : gender,
       "dbname" : //dbname from url will come here
      });
  };
</script>
```

now i want to use the dbname in my overview.html part to send it as a parameter for backend calls. I can load it directly in my js file but that will not serve my purpose. How can it be done.

Comment: why don't you use a view engine? Then you can easily send dbname into the rendered view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to take a look at a template engine such as [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) or [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug)

Comment: i used pug for that purpose. and i am able to send the parameter. can you help me with on thing that i want the parameter to be receive as a string and i am just getting it as the vaue. The way i am sending it is :

pug.renderFile('filename',{dbname : 'value'})

Comment: what do you mean by _i want the parameter to be receive as a string and i am just getting it as the value_? What does the value look like?

Comment: this is the way i have the parameter after i render the file         : 
 
    "dbname" : value ;
 
but i want it to be like :

    "dbname" : "value"

Comment: Oh I see, pug will not include the quotes around the strings in the template. If you want them you need to add them manually, like this "#{dbname}"

Answer (score 0):

You are using res.sendFile, so you cannot pass any data with it because that just reads a file from disk and streams it as the response, giving you no chance to modify it

You need template systems to accomplish your task (EJS,Handlebars,Mustache)